# How to download an attachment from a direct web URL and saving it in my local machine using Java?

Tags: java, download, attachment, fileoutputstream, httpsurlconnection

I am trying to download an Attachment from a direct https web URL using Java.
eg., https://DNS/secure/attachment/1165147/RegressionTestingPlugin.zip
I am able to download the Attachment, but it is Just 2 KB. I have tried many methods, but it doesn't helps.
Can you help me in this?

METHOD 1

```
URL url3 = new URL(AttachmentURL);
HttpsURLConnection httpConnection1= (HttpsURLConnection) url3.openConnection();                             
httpConnection1 = (HttpsURLConnection) url3.openConnection();
httpConnection1.setRequestProperty("Accept", "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange");
httpConnection1.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Basic DummyAUTH");
httpConnection1.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/octet-stream");
OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream("C:/IssueIDs/"+AttachmentName, true);
os.close();
```

METHOD 2

```
URL url4 = new URL(AttachmentURL);
URLConnection connection = url4.openConnection();
InputStream inputstream = connection.getInputStream();
FileSystemView filesys = FileSystemView.getFileSystemView();
filesys.getHomeDirectory();
BufferedOutputStream bufferedoutputstream = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(new File("C:\\IssueIDs\\"+AttachmentName)));
byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
int bytesRead;
while((bytesRead = inputstream.read(buffer)) > 0)
{ 
    bufferedoutputstream.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
}
bufferedoutputstream.flush();
bufferedoutputstream.close();
inputstream.close();
```

Comment: Have you tried using using the "Java NIO" package ? e.g see https://www.baeldung.com/java-download-file#using-nio

Comment: Hi Senjoux, Thanks for the suggestion, I just tried it. I am facing the same Issue in this case as well.

Comment: @Saravana Could you edit the question to include errors or stack traces that you get when you run the program? That will help other members to follow what is going on and we may be able to help you better.

Comment: Hello, I am not getting any such errors, but the generated file is just 2 KB.

Comment: Have you tried to use [`HttpURLConnection`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html) and check the response code using `#getResponseCode()`? Maybe your server is rejecting the authentication.

Answer (score 0):

Why reinvent the wheel, try apache commons io package. It is simple to use. I personally use the following API to download files locally . (@criztovyl , thanks for the suggestion.)

```
FileUtils.copyURLToFile(source, destination, connectionTimeout, readTimeout);
```

The code goes below.

```
import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;
import java.net.URL;
import java.io.File;
import java.util.Date;

class DownloadFile{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
        String fileNameToDownload = "pathToFile"; // https://helloworld.com/file.txt
        URL source = new URL(args[0]+fileNameToDownload);
        File destination = new File(args[1]+File.separator+fileNameToDownload);
        long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        System.out.println("initiated Download at "+new Date(start));
        int connectionTimeout = 5*1000;
        int readTimeout = 30*60*1000;
        FileUtils.copyURLToFile(source, destination, connectionTimeout, readTimeout);
        long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
        System.out.println("Copleted downloading at "+new Date(end));
        System.out.println("Time taken to download file is "+(end-start)/1000+" seconds");
    }
}
```

Quick security tip :
Also, from your example, if you are trying in production, then please consider using proper hostnameverifier and SSLContext for the httpsurlconnection object.

Comment: It might improve your answer to explicitly add that you suggest to use  `FileUtils#copyURLToFile`.